# Java Compiler Program

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, javac

So, I have got to the stage where if I type command `javac showargs.java` it works but when I type command `java ShowArgs` I get the message: Error: Could not find or load main class ShowArgs.

Comment: hi, please attach some code

Comment: type `java showargs` all shorthand if your class name is `showargs` or type the actual class name case sensitively

Comment: C:\> javac ShowArgs.java

Comment: C:\> java ShowArgs -> that is where the error starts

Answer (score 0):

try,

java -cp *

E.g.:

java -cp * com.example.ShowArgs

Comment: Tried that, it just gave me a list of options, any particular option?

Comment: 1. Place ShowArgs class in a package (Eg: package com.example.ShowArgs)
2. java -cp * com.example.ShowArgs

Comment: How do I grant access

Answer (score 0):

If you had provided the `code` which causes that error would be more helpfull for me to suggest you a solution. But there are some hacks anyways to solve errors :

Follow the below steps to solve your error :

1 . Just remove the `public` keyword from the class which contains your      `public static void main()`      method .

2.If the error isn't solved by implementing the above step rename your class which contains the `main` method to `any_name_you_like`.

I hope this will solve the error. :)

Comment: please post here your `code` to rectify the exact error then,

Comment: java showargs Error: Could not find or load main class showargs

Comment: Instead of typing `java ShowArgs` , type `java showargs` . Let me know if that worked.

Comment: I'm in C:\ do I have to be where the file was saved

Comment: @AaronBoyse : yes , your file is saved in `bin` directory of the `java-sdk` . In that case you need to enter into the `bin` directory and then type `java showargs` command .